# space to do a system-upgrade

Tags: upgrade, disk-usage

I want to upgrade a 20.04 system (xubuntu) to 22.04.

```
LANG=C df
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5               30G   25G  3,6G  88% /
/dev/loop6             500M  3,6M  419M   1% /var/lib/machines
/dev/sda6               36G   31G  2,8G  92% /home
```

There is 3.6G free space on the partition/fs which will be used. There would be 2.8G free space, to store temporary files, if needed and possible.

Will the upgrade work? Is it possible, to specify a dedicated device to store temporary files? How many free space do I need - roughly - during install, and permanently (the last q. is not answerable without knowing, which packages I installed, which will in turn get upgraded. But maybe for a plain install.)

Comment: you can probably mount a dedicated device as your temp folder, if that's what you want. Not sure exactly what issues you might come across doing that, though.